# How to print the 1st line of a command’s output to screen, then sort the rest on col 6 and print that to screen?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, command-line

Using the Linux command line, I would like to:

— print the first line (from a command’s output) to screen
— then sort the rest of the output by column 6, and print that to the screen too

I’m sure there are `sed` and `awk` solutions, but I’d like to do it with the minimum complexity /{so I can remember it and probably use it again!/}

The sort I’ve done, for example:  df -h | sort -k 6
returns something *like*

```
/dev/sda9  100G  33G  6.0G  23%  /
tmpfs      6.3G  3.4M 6.2G   1%  /dev/shm
/dev/sda2  10G   3G   6.0G  80%  /home
Filesystem Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
```

This sorts the header line into the output.
Thanks for your kind assistance.

I tried the sort using `-k 6` to sort on 6th column, but didn’t know how to both not include the header line in the sort, for ex: `df -h | tail -n +2 | sort -k 6`
that works, but doesn’t display the header at all.

Comment: Hmmm, it stripped out the line breaks making it a lot harder to read

Comment: `df -h | { IFS= read -r line; printf '%s\n' "$line"; sort -k 6; }`